# Tomcat error: Resource Not Available (HTTP 404)

Tags: java, xml, jsp, tomcat, struts

I'm just trying a very simple webapp that converts temperature from celcius to °F and K.

All the source code, xml, etc, is supposed to be correct because I took it from a book.

Java version - 1.7

Tomcat version - 8.0

OS: Windows 8.0

The error shows up when I enter http://localhost:8080/lab4/.

Tomcat is running correctly and I can deploy and use other webapps.

Also, I'm using a custom tag called convert.

Java Class Handler

```
package net.thinksquared.lab4;

import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTagSupport;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyContent;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;
import javax.servlet.jsp.*;


public class Converter extends BodyTagSupport{

    private String _to;

    public String getTo() {
        return _to;
    }   

    public void setTo(String to) {
        _to = to;
    }

    public int doAfterBody(){

        try {
            BodyContent bc = getBodyContent();
            JspWriter out = bc.getEnclosingWriter();
            double result = 0.0;
            double temp = Double.parseDouble(bc.getString());
            if(_to.equals("F")) {
                result = toFahrenheit(temp);
            } else {
                result = toKelvin(temp);  
            }
            bc.getEnclosingWriter().print(result);

        } catch(Exception E) {

        }      
        return EVAL_PAGE; //tells servlet container to process rest of JSP page.
    }

    private double toFahrenheit(double c){
        return 32.0 + (c*1.8);
    }

    private double toKelvin(double c){
        return 273.0 + c;
    }

}
```

JSP

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html language="java";charset=UTF-8" %>

<%@ taglib uri="/tags/lab4-converter" prefix="temp" %>
<temp:convert to="F">100</temp:convert>
```

TLD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.1//EN" 
                        "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd">

<taglib>
    <tlibversion>1.2</tlibversion>
    <jspversion>1.1</jspversion>

    <tag>
        <name>convert</name>
        <tagClass>net.thinksquared.lab4.Converter</tagClass>
        <bodyContent>JSP</bodyContent>
        <attribute>
            <name>to</name>
            <required>no</required>
        </attribute>

    </tag>

<taglib>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE web-app
  PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd">

<web-app>
  <display-name>Lab4: Custom Tags</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>test.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>  

<taglib>
    <taglib-uri>/tags/lab4-converter</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/lab4-converter.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>

</web-app>
```

Finally, I have this batch for compiling and building.
compile.bat

```
@echo off

REM ----------------------------------------------------------------------
REM     This batch file creates a WAR file for Lab 4, the lab on custom tags. 
REM The output is lab4.war.
REM
REM     NOTE: To get this batch file on your system, you should change the 
REM     PATH variable to point to your JDK location.
REM ----------------------------------------------------------------------

set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin
set APP_NAME=lab4

echo Cleaning up build directory
rmdir /S/Q build

echo Creating buildnment directory
mkdir build\WEB-INF\classes

echo Installing web.xml and .tld files
copy .\web\WEB-INF\*.* .\build\WEB-INF\*.*

echo Installing web pages 
copy .\web\ .\build\

echo Compiling java code
javac -deprecation -d build/WEB-INF/classes -classpath ./lib/jsp-api.jar ./src/*.java


cd build

echo creating WAR file
jar cvf %APP_NAME%.war .
copy %APP_NAME%.war ..

pause
```

[I'm working with these directory:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEIV4.png)

[image]

Comment: If you get 404 using  http://localhost:8080/lab4/ , then that means your welcome file can't be found. Therefore the tag code is not relevant. Also, you can the manager app to see if your web app has been loaded and is running.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your project directory is already under webapps in Tomcat is making this difficult. You can either:

1. move your project directory elsewhere and make your compile script place the lab4.war file into the webapps folder (recommended), or
2. you can alter your source folder structure (not recommended) to move everything in the web folder up into the lab4 folder.

The webapps folder should contain either *.war files or folders that contain the web application and the WEB-INF folder. Your structure meets neither of these.

Also, just moving your war file into the webapps folder will likely cause a problem because it will want to unpack to a folder called lab4 - which is where your project is. This will probably end badly for you.

Comment: I tried the 1st option. I deleted lab4 folder and placed lab4.war in webapps. I received the same error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The TLD was incorrect.

The correct one is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.1//EN" 
                        "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd">

<taglib>

    <tlibversion>1.2</tlibversion>
    <jspversion>1.1</jspversion>
    <shortname>temp</shortname>

    <tag>
        <name>convert</name>
        <tagclass>net.thinksquared.lab4.Converter</tagclass>
        <bodyContent>JSP</bodyContent>
        <attribute>
            <name>to</name>
            <required>no</required>
        </attribute>

    </tag>

</taglib>
```

I also did what Jason suggested: placed the lab4.war in webapps and deleted the folder lab4.